# Creating a Generic that Always Extends the Class Using it

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to design a special type of collection that may only contain elements of its own type. This collection class must also be extendable. At first glance, this seems like a simple enough task:

```
public class MyClass<E extends MyClass> implements Collection<E>{
    //insert Collection<E> methods here...
}
```

However, because one of these collections may only contain elements that are instances of its class, the following shouldn't be possible:

```
public class MySubclass extends MyClass<MyClass>{}
```

What I need is a version of MyClass that essentially does the following (don't try to compile this one):

```
public class MyClass<E extends this.getClass()> implements Collection<E>{...}
```

Is it possible to implement something like this? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the signature your are looking for would be something like this:

```
 public class MyClass<E extends MyClass<E>> ...
```

The problem with this, and why I don't think you can enforce what you want from a declaration standpoint is that you have an infinite loop. If the collection may only contain elements of its own type, then elements can only contain elements of itself, etc, etc.

You now have an infinite loop where you may only contain Collections and at no point will you have a Collection that contains some THING.

Also, remember that at runtime type-erasure does away with all generic type. Therefore, no matter how fancy your generic declaration is at any point someone could do the following and just get a warning:

```
 new MyClass();
```

That is another reason why trying to enforce this type of structure probably won't work well.

Instead you could put an appropriate check in the `add` method that would provide runtime enforcement. Still have the infinite loop issue though.

**EDIT**

To do runtime checking, do the following:

```
public boolean add(E element){
     if (!(element instanceof MyClass))
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element is not an instance of MyClass");

    // rest of add code here
}
```

Comment: The “infinite loop” might be acceptable when a tree of nodes of equal type is desired. And `new MyClass();` can easily forbidden by making `MyClass` `abstract`.

Comment: WRT abstract, could still do `SubClass extends MyClass{}`. In Java there is no requirement to use generics, it just gives the raw type warning.

Comment: +1 (if I could) for the signature; it disallows MySubclass extending MyClass<MyClass>, which is a step in the right direction! However, making MySubclass extend MyClass still allows a superclass to be added to it (only up to MyClass though, not Object). And yes, Holger is correct, a chain of nodes is exactly what is desired here; the collections are fully intended to be the only THINGs ever stored.

Perhaps that runtime enforced adding could be of use to me. Would you mind demonstrating how to go about doing such a thing?

Comment: That’s right you can’t enforce use of generics but there are a lot of other things which can be circumvented too if you really try. The important thing is that the compiler will guide you the intended way. More important is that if you have a `MySubclass` fulfilling the generic signature you can still create a Generics-conforming subclass of `MySubclass` violating the intention without getting a warning. The base class cannot enforce its subclasses to be `final`.

Comment: That would imply I'm no longer looking for solutions, no? I feel it's probably best to reserve that for when I've got an acceptable answer or this is shown to be outright impossible to implement. I definitely appreciate the input from both of you, though! I'll be sure to check up on this later today.

Comment: I suppose that's probably the closest I'll get to this sort of behavior with what you guys have been explaining about type-erasure and generics. Thanks a ton for all the help!